# How to link tables in an update statement using Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update all the rows on table A, where A.id = B.id and B.code is some value.

Something like:

```
UPDATE table_a
 SET processed = 'Y'
 WHERE table_a.id = table_b.id AND
       table_b.code = 'ABC';
```

Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are quick workaround for your problem.

```
UPDATE 
(
 SELECT 
   a.processed, a.id 
 FROM 
   table_a a, 
   table_b b
 WHERE 
   a.id = b.id 
 AND 
   b.code = 'ABC'
 ) u
SET u.processed = 'Y'
```

OR

```
UPDATE table_a a
SET a.processed = 'Y'
WHERE a.id IN
(SELECT b.id FROM table_b b WHERE b.code = 'ABC')
```

Hope this might Help!

Answer (score -1):

You have to reference second table before you can use it. You can use a subselect:

```
UPDATE table_a SET processed = 'Y' 
WHERE table_a.id = (SELECT table_b.id FROM table_b WHERE table_b.code = 'ABC');
```

The subselect returns a list of ids from table_b fulfilling the condition table_b.code = 'ABC'. Update will effect those rows in table_a with table_a.id in the list from subselect.